# Move Files to New Directory based on SQL Query Data

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hoping someone could help:)

I have an MS Access table that holds file names along with other data Example:
AcctNum, FileName
12345, abc123.pdf

I have written a SQL to sort the file name based on account number. Example: Select * from tblTest where AcctNum='12345'

Files with these file names are located in a directory (`C:\Test\<filename>.pdf`)

I need to move the selected files based on the SQL I've written to move those files to a different directory (D:\Test\FromCode). Filename 'abc123.pdf' is located in C:\Test move to D:\test, loop through SQL results to move files based on criteria.

Attached is some VBA that I have written that I can get a file to copy from source to destination manually when I input the exact filename (as seen in the code, the file name is "abc123"), but I want to tie it to the mysql query recordset and move the group which will contain 1000's of files. Anyone know the best way I can tie this to recordset?

Appreciate any direction/help you provide.

```
Sub UpdateDirectory()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim mysource As String
Dim mydes As String
Dim mysql As String


mysql = "SELECT * from tblTest where ACCTNUM = 123456"
mysource = "C:\Test"
mydes = "D:\Test\FromCode\"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mysource)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(mysql)


'I want to tie mysql recordset to below to move all files/records based 
'on ACCTNUM. This could result in moving 1000's of files to 
'destination.

 For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
     If InStr(1, objFile.Name, "abc123") > 0 Then
         Debug.Print "yes"
         objFSO.CopyFile objFile, mydes
     Else
         Debug.Print "no"
     End If
 Next

 'clean
Set objFolder = Nothing
 Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with a working answer:  To be sure, @June7 is correct, but putting the answer in your context:

```
Sub UpdateDirectory()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim mysource As String
Dim mydes As String
Dim mysql As String


mysql = "SELECT * from tblTest where ACCTNUM = 123456"
mysource = "C:\Test" 'Missing backslash - added later
mydes = "D:\Test\FromCode\"


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(mysource)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordSet(mysql)


'I want to tie mysql recordset to below to move all files/records based 
'on ACCTNUM. This could result in moving 1000's of files to 
'destination.

While Not rs.EOF
    sourceFile = mysource & "\" & rs!Filename 'Added a missing backslash
    destFile = mydes & rs!Filename

    If Dir(sourceFile) <> "" Then 'If sourceFile exists, then Dir(sourceFile) will return it's name, otherwise empty string
        FileCopy sourceFile, destFile 
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: And I know I'll catch flack for saying this, but your ending with ```  'clean
Set objFolder = Nothing
 Set objFile = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing``` is not required because when the interpreter sees End Sub, it throws away any references you created during that sub.  Many will argue that it's good coding practice but imho, it's just unnecessary noise.

Comment: Thanks June and Scott! Appreciate the help and direction. 

When executing the code, it's moving the first file the SQL finds in the filter, but only loops and moves that 1 file; after it has looped through the entire filter, I get the permission denied error (most likely because that file already exists). in my debug.print rs!filename I see the same file repeated 100 times.

Comment: OOPS!  I forgot rs.MoveNext to move to the next record in the recordset (right before the Wend statment.  Edited....).  I guess that's what I get for writing code in a browser without running it :)

Comment: Glad it worked.  Can I persuade you to give this answer the check mark then?

Comment: Will do Scott.
Additional question though. 

I have been trying to modify the code a bit based on my SQL filter as the file structure has changed (instead of file name I must move folder)
Instead of filename, I'm trying to move folder contents based on folder name. I have directories that are named by date/then by unique folder names; example: 
Test/
ABC1234/
ABC567/
ABD8999
and I want to move the folder contents with the folder name to a different location, how can I accomplish that? When I changed my SQL and source, it recognized my new SQL, but didn't move the folder and contents.

Comment: Best to ask a separate question (mostly to get you answers from more than just me, but also affects my 'rep' score for answering multiple questions.)  But here's the gist:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/movefolder-method  That document basically means that instead of copying sourceFile to destFile, you'd create a File System Object (fso) and do a fso.MoveFoder sourceFolder, destFolder.  If you'd like a code sample given the above context, open another question and invite me to answer and I'll generate one for you.

Answer (score 0):

That SQL is not sorting records, it is filtering.

The recordset serves no purpose if you do not loop through records. If you do not want to simply copy all files and the complete account number is not part of filename, then need to loop through recordset, not folder. Use filename from field in the file copy. FSO is not needed - Access FileCopy method can serve.

```
...
mysource = "C:\Test\"
...
Do While Not rs.EOF
   If Dir(mysource & rs!Filename) <> "" Then FileCopy mysource & rs!Filename, mydes & rs!Filename
Loop
```

Comment: How would i be able to use the MoveFolder method based on my SQL Filter? My requirements have changed a bit, and instead of moving files, I need to move the entire directory under a subfolder based on my SQL Filter.

Comment: I believe that does require FSO. A web search will find examples like https://analystcave.com/vba-filesystemobject-fso-in-excel/vba-movefolder/. If you need more help then post a new question.